# How to serialize just one value of input via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I started to do dropdown list instead select bcz it is not possible to stylize but I did not think to future and now I found that if I want to save data from form to db I need to get ids via $_POST instead of names.

For ex. I have dropdown list with status of product:
`New`
`Old`
`Handmade`

If I want to save chosen sattus for chosen product it is better for me to get ID of status option. Bcz my table is like this:

```
item_id | option_value
1       | 1
```

If I send name as "old" via $_POST, I need to get its ID from another table before insert it.

I created dropdown list like this:

```
    /* SELECT REPLACED BY DIV JS */

    var select = $('.add-item__select').hide(); // Hide original select options

    // Replace each select by div
    select.each(function() {
        var selectVal = $(this).find('.add-item__select-main').text(),
            name = $(this).attr('name');

        newDropdownDiv = $('<input class="add-item__input-select" name="' + name + '" placeholder="' + selectVal + '" readonly required><i class="arrow down"></i></input>')
            .insertAfter($(this))
            .css({paddingLeft: '0.3em', cursor: 'pointer'});
    });
```

Each SELECT has addaed INPUT after it.

If I want to show shosen vale from dropdown list I need to show it in this way:

```
$('.add-item__input-select').val("text copied from list");
```

After this if I add ID of option to input in this way:

```
$('.add-item__input-select').attr("value", optionID);
```

Then If I want to serialize all fields values from form and **this is point**,
`$('.add-item__form').serializeArray()`
I get two results for status:
`name: "status", value: "text copied from list"`
and
`name: "status", value: optionID`

**But I need just optionID.**

I have everything optimized for this structure, so I would like to ask you if there is some easy way how to fix it or I need to modify structure.

I am thinking to remove INPUT and just change SELECT opacity to 0 instead of display none and use SELECT for form data serialize. But then I will need to replace all INPUTs by some DIV which will hold text of chosen option and also change everything else connected with it. For ex, if user clicked on INPUT the label was showed above it.

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution but I have problem that it is working just if user will not refresh page. In DOM is everything the same after refresh but serializeArray() get just input text value and not value="ID" after page refresh.

I just remove these values which I do not want from FormData.

```
    // Send formData to upload.php
    $('.add-item__form').on('submit', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        if ( checkFieldsIfNotEmpty() == true ) {
            var formDataFields = $('.add-item__form').serializeArray(), // Get all data from form except of photos
                count = Object.keys(data).length; // count fields of object

            // Fill formData object by data from form
            $.each(formDataFields, function(index, value) {
                if ( value.name === 'category' && !$.isNumeric(value.value) || value.name === 'subcategory' && !$.isNumeric(value.value) ) {
                    // do nothing
                } else if ( (value.name.indexOf('filter') >= 0) && !$.isNumeric(value.value) ) {
                    // do nothing
                }
                else {
                    formData.append(value.name, value.value); // add name and value to POST data
                }

            });

            // foreach - fill formData with photos from form
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                formData.append('files[]', value);
            });

            uploadData(formData); // send data via ajax to upload.php
        }
    });
```

Can you advice me what can be problem?